# MySQL compare value of field in one table with value of row in a different table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm new to SQL and very confused on how to achieve the following:

Update **TableA.row1.result** with "equal", if **TableA.row1.fieldA** is equal to the value in **TableB.fieldA.columnZ** (notice in TableB, the row is named "fieldA", which has the same name given to the column in TableA).

I have this so far, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the update.

```
SELECT TableA.rowname from TableA 
      INNER JOIN TableB on TableA.fieldA=TableB.fieldID
```

Comment: you should sqlfiddle.com some data and then let us know which rows you're trying to update

Answer (score 0):

You should read about multi-table updates ([link to mySQL official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/update.html))

Try to use this template for your queries.

```
update TableA, TableB
set TableA.row1_result = TableB.fieldA_columnZ
where TableA.fieldA=TableB.fieldID
```